# React hook mock in jest ESM mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs, mocking

I've been trying for several hours making my test pass.

I'm using `Next.js` `v12` with the [recommended](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-the-rust-compiler) `jest` setup (with Rust compiler).

I'm also running jest in [ESM mode](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) using the `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest` option.

I've got a really simple (and standard setup) which in my opinion should work out of the box:

The test view:

```js
// Test.tsx
import { useTest } from "../../hooks/useTest";

export const Test = () => {
  const { test } = useTest();
  return <div>{test}</div>; // <<--- returns state from the hook
};
```

Which imports the following `useTest` hook:

```js
// useTest.ts
import { useState } from "react";

export const useTest = () => {
  const [test] = useState("original"); // <<--- I expect this to be mocked with `mocked` in the test

  return { test };
};
```

And finally the test: ([jest recommended setup](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm))

```js
// Test.test.tsx
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

jest.unstable_mockModule("../hooks/useTest", () => {
  return {
    useTest: () => {
      return {
        test: "mocked",
      };
    },
  };
});

const { useTest } = await import("../hooks/useTest");
// const mockUseTest = useTest as jest.MockedFunction<typeof useTest>;

import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Test } from "../components/wallet/Test";

describe("test hook mocking", () => {
  it("mocks hook as expected", async () => {
    // mockUseTest.mockImplementation(() => ({ test: "mocked" }));
    render(<Test />);

    await screen.findByText("mocked");
  });
});
```

I'm always getting

> ● test hook mocking › mocks hook as expected

```
Unable to find an element with the text: mocked. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      original
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

  22 |     render(<Test />);
  23 |
> 24 |     await screen.findByText("mocked");
     |                  ^
  25 |   });
  26 | });
  27 |
```

which obviously means that always the `original` state is returned from the hook instead of the mocked module.

I've tried multiple variations of the test file

- with and without `awiat import("../hooks/useTest")`
- with `jest.mock` instead of `jest.unstable_mockModule`
- with `jest.mock` without the return value - which [according to the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) creates automatic mock
- with `__esModule: true` on the returned from the mock object
- trying to mockImplementation (as you can see in the test file commented out)

All the paths are correct and triple checked.

Not really sure where to go from here...

Comment: Testing implementation details like this in general is not a good way to write tests. Why not just simply test whether 'original' is visible on the screen?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, notice `screen.findByText("mocked")` in the test. I'm testing the view, not the hook, in line with RTL recommendations and testing standards.

Comment: May I did not do a good job explaining what I meant. Here you are directly mocking the state and testing it, you should instead test some user interaction which will update the corresponding state which will then update what is rendered on the screen and you should check for that in your tests.

Comment: That's completely fine, the focus of this question is different though. I've provided this minimal example to highlight that `jest` doesn't seem to be working with ES modules, even thought this is what they recommend in their docs, so I wanted to see whether anyone has done module mocking in ESM successfully.