# Next.js jest support for 3rd party enabled ESM npm packages

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, jestjs

I'm between a rock and a hard place.

I've created my app using:

- `t3-stack`: `v6.2.1` - [T3 stack](https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app)
- `Next.js`: `v12.3.1`
- `jest`: `v29.3.1`

I've followed the `Next.js` docs on the `jest` setup (with the Rust Compiler) https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-the-rust-compiler

I also included https://wagmi.sh/ (React Hooks for Ethereum) to my project, so far all great and dandy until I started testing my components.

In one of my test files I had to create a mocked `wagmi` client so I had to import a few packages from `wagmi` to my test file like so:

`import { Client, createClient, WagmiConfig, useConnect } from "wagmi";`

And then I run the test:

So the first issue I've come across was the classic:

> .../node_modules/wagmi/dist/index.js:2
> import { createSyncStoragePersister } from "@tanstack/query-sync-storage-persister";
> ^^^^^^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> ```

I tried multiple different options in the `jest.config.js` file:

- `filters`
- `transformIgnorePatters`

but nothing helped with transforming the `wagmi` esm enabled library.

I went to the `jest` docs and started reading - I can fix it using [the ECMAScript Modules support](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules)

I ended up adding `extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts", ".tsx"]` to my `jest.config.js` file
and now I can just use my test with `nodejs` flag:

`NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest -- src/__tests__/Wallet.test.tsx`

Everything works, amazing!

Few days goes by and I need to mock a hook!

I go to `jest` docs again and read on [how to mock modules in ESM mode](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm).

Nope, I can't mock hooks!  Tried million different setups.
Which I've described in [the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578568/react-hook-mock-in-jest-esm-mode?noredirect).

Ok, so I go back to my original setup without ESM support.
Without the ESM (node experimental flag) `jest.mock` works as expected.

Not so fast, now I'm back at square one, because I can't `imoprt` `wagmi` since it's ESM enabled.

So how do I import npm packages that are ESM modules?

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my own question, just in case anyone comes across the same issue:

The whole problem stems from the fact that `jest` does not yet (as of writing this post) fully support `node ESM mode` and whenever a `esModule` is being loaded, `jest` cannot interpret it correctly.

The other issue is that in the Next.js distribution version there is the `next/dist/build/jest/jest.js` file that prevents from overriding `testPathIgnorePatterns` configuration option.

Considering both of the issues, you either have to use:

- `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules` with `jest`

  - this loads ESM modules but you can't properly use `jest.mock` which I've [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578568/react-hook-mock-in-jest-esm-mode).
- or the second option is to hack around `next.js` `jest` config file [described here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31152#discussioncomment-1697047)

  - This allows for transpiling ESM modules before running the tests which is the option I went for.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue with NextJS and Wagmi.

As described above using `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules` in test command and `extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts", ".tsx"],` in `jest.config.js` worked but with one issue:

`Referance error: jest is not defined` in order to solve this I installed `@jest/globals` with `pnpm add @jest/globals` and in every test file I imported jest with `import { jest } from "@jest/globals"`

my final `jest.config.js`:

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts", ".tsx"],
  transform: {},
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

and test command:

```json
"test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest --ci --silent",
```

Comment: Yup, this works, but bear in mind `jest.mock` won't work for you with this setup unfortunately, I've spent hours trying to make it work to no avail.
Until I'm missing something and you can successfully use `jest.mock` to mock npm modules?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct solution, but I replaced jest with vitest and it works out of the box following the config found in this repository: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-vitest